# How to add tint to layout as in android youtube video player?

Tags: android, android-layout

How can I add tint at decreasing levels to a layout?

[image]

Comment: Trying to add to a normal layout or for a youtube player?

Comment: I'm trying to add it to LinearLayout.

Comment: You want a Gradient. You can achieve this in different ways. I.e.: using a 9 patch or a GradientDrawable. Or even directly drawing on the Canvas, but this would be an overkill.

Comment: Thanks Rotwang for the suggestions,GradientDrawable should fit the job.

Comment: Personally, I'd go with a 9 patch, since I could control it precisely.

Answer (score 1):

Create a `drawable` as below and set it as background for layout

```
<shape
  android:shape="rectangle"
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <gradient android:angle="270"
          android:startColor="#333333"
          android:centerColor="#FFFFFF"
          android:endColor="#333333"/>
</shape>
```

Comment: I tried this already but I'm unable to achieve the same level of tinting.Is there any way to add more parameters in the center of start,center and endcolor?

Comment: @Naveen No. There's only 3 positions.

Comment: @Naveen if you want to control the colors and the positions use `LinearGradient` class